# webpack-dev-server: command not found on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a node.js application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk, I have compressed, uploaded and deployed the application. I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway | nginx/1.12.1 | error. So I had a look at the logs:

> sh: webpack-dev-server: command not found.

So the problem is clear. However I am under the impression that AWS runs npm install when initialising the application (per their docs) and that webpack is a listed dependancy in my package.json file. So my question is, how can I get the command to run to run my server?

New to deployment so thanks for any help in advance!

John

Comment: Do you install `webpack-dev-server` globally? In that case it might not be in your global packages or npm might be looking for it in wrong folder? How about using `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` command or using `npx` or `yarn` to run it?

Comment: @BorisBurkov Thanks for your response! on my local machine it is installed globally! can I install it globally on the server? I will try the `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` command in the meantime and report back!

Comment: John, unfortunately I haven't worked with ElasticBeanstalk, so I don't know exactly, how your deployment works. Personally I believe that those global packages were a terrible idea and avoid using them, installing everything as devDependencies.`npx`, `yarn`, `node_moules/.bin` or `node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin`

Comment: @BorisBurkov I have them installed as devDependencies as well, I think the global was from a previous project. Unfortunately I still haven't figured it out yet, the EB logs aren't very helpful and even after I think I've solved the webpack issue it persists. I think I'll sleep on it overnight and try again in the morning. Thanks again for all your help and suggestions!